¿Laravel firstOrCreate no funciona en Json?
¿Por qué el metodo firstOrCreate no funciona en registros del tipo array o json?
Mi variable $items es un array
[
   ['prouct_id' => $prouct_id,  'prouct_name => $prouct_name, ...],
   ['prouct_id' => $prouct_id,  'prouct_name => $prouct_name, ...],
]

Al ejecutar el método firstOrCreate en el campo  $table->json('items'); no encuentra la información aunque la variable $item es la misma, siempre crea nuevos registros aunque estos ya existan.
Estuve buscando información y veo que  no se puede ejecutar la sentencia sql WHERE en un array o Json, a de ser por eso que el método firstOrCreate no funciona y siempre crea nuevos registros.
¿Como puedo solucionar este problema en laravel?
Lo mas fácil seria hacer una búsqueda manual SELECT * FROM orders WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(items, ...
o pasar la variable $items a texto json_encode($items), pero me gustaría saber si esto se puede solucionar desde Laravel y poder conserval el campo  $table->json('items'); como json y no como varchar.
Order::firstOrCreate(
    [
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'items' => $items
    ],
    [
        'email_id' => $user->email,
        ...
        ...
        ...
    ]
);

Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('email_id')->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('phone_id')->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('address_id')->constrained();
    $table->string('address_reference', 50)->nullable();
    $table->json('items');
    $table->double('total');
    $table->enum('status', ["arrival","verifying_payment","paid","sent","delivered","returned","cancel"])->default('arrival');
    $table->timestamps();
});


Y por qué tienes un campo json en tu tabla para almacenar información de los objetos?? Yo creo que el problema original es un mal diseño de tu base de datos, donde tu campo actual "items" debería ser una segunda tabla enlazada con la primera de órdenes, que es el patrón con el que siempre se han hecho este tipo de cosas, y por algo será que se usa en este caso siempre :) Tienes toda la potencia de una base de datos y estás gastándola en hacerle almacenar un tocho de texto que apenas entiende... Tu actual esquema de base de datos no sigue ninguna forma normal, normalízala y no tendrás problemas

De hecho asi la tengo, pero para simplificar mi pregunta la puse en la tabla de ordenes, Pero originalmente tengo el item_id en la tabla de ordenes, he notado que el 80 % de las compras son de los mismos productos, asi que para no agregar mas espacio usando siempre la misma información de los mismos productos, solo agrego el item_id, adicionalmente se usa una API, en donde el equipo de riesgo se encarga de analizar si envía el pedido o no, es por eso que la información de Items debe de ir en Json, ya que el endpoint debe de ser compatible con otros lenguajes, debo evitar la serialización

Ese comportamiento está reportado en un issue desde hace mucho tiempo https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17282, pero hace poco en laracast dijeron que en laravel 11 estaba funcionando bien https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/firstorcreate-on-json-field
